# Offline documentation for various programming languages?

Tags: documentation, offline

I recently found this: http://php.net/get/php_manual_en.chm/from/a/mirror.
It's a .chm file that contains all the documentation for PHP which you can normally find on their site. Handy for offline use.

I'm wondering, does anybody know of similar things for other languages. Complete offline documentation that you can use if you don't have wireless for a while.

For C#, Visual Studio gives you the option to download and install the entire online documentation as a part of the VS2008 install, so if you have Visual Studio 2008, then you have the C# offline documentation.

EDIT: if you're gonna say this and that is possible, please post hyperlinks.

This is what we have now:

- PHP: [http://be.php.net/get/php_manual_en.chm/from/a/mirror](http://php.net/get/php_manual_en.chm/from/a/mirror)
- Java: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp#docs
- C: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/
- MS SQL server: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=765433F7-0983-4D7A-B628-0A98145BCB97
- Python 2.x: http://docs.python.org/download.html
- Python 3.x: http://docs.python.org/py3k/download.html
- Ruby: http://railsapi.com/
- The Common Lisp HyperSpec: ftp://ftp.lispworks.com/pub/software_tools/reference/
- The complete MSDN library: no longer available, sadly
- The Visual Studio 2008 SP1 offline library: https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7BBE5EDA-5062-4EBB-83C7-D3C5FF92A373&displaylang=en

Comment: The PHP-manual for offline use, should link to this: http://php.net/download-docs.php You can download a single html-file, a bunch of html-files and a chm-file.

Comment: This should be a community wiki

Comment: Check out this chrome APP that puts PHP documentation right n your browser. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-docs-to-go/mlilmganaobieaclflbciblffhaagnip

Comment: Checkout [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/)

Comment: DevDocs – now only some web development related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most language should provide that.

Some examples:

Java: [Java SE 6 docs (below on the page)](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

Perl: Unix versions of perl typically come with full docs as manpages and perldoc (some Linux distributions put these into extra packages); I suppose Windows versions do the same

C: the GNU libc library has [downloadable docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/)

Answer (score 18):

Dash http://kapeli.com/dash includes offline documentation for 150+ APIs.

Comment: Equivalent for Windows and Linux: open source [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/)

Comment: This is a good still valid answer.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks a lot for saving time to search for every problem i run into

Answer (score 2):

Python also has [downloadable documentation](http://docs.python.org/download.html). As a result, most operating systems which provide Python also provides a documentation package. For instance, on Debian, this is package `python2.5-doc` (one package per version).

Install it and you can browse the documentation offline. Very convenient for a laptop which is not always connected.

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery, I recommend jQAPI - Alternative jQuery Documentation Browser, that you can find here: http://www.jqapi.com/

You can use it online as well as download it for offline use.

Answer (score 1):

btw, the Visual Studio docs (MSDN) also include documentation for JScript, VBScript, HTML and CSS.  Back when I programmed PERL I always installed perldoc.

Downloading the documentation is pretty much the first thing I do if I've got any serious work to do in an unfamiliar language.  Just reading through the API is like mining gold!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with the C# specification, installed by default in

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Specifications\1033`

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server ships with a whole load of documentation know as "Books Online". Despite the name you can downlaod these from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=765433F7-0983-4D7A-B628-0A98145BCB97&displaylang=en).

Comment: a -1 more than 3 years after I posted an answer, yet no comment? I'd be interested to hear why...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby, Rack, Rails, and several gems can all be found at [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is great for C++ and C reference. They also have offline versions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives).

Comment: Only the search does not work there (at least I am not aware of a way to run it).

Answer (score 0):

For Java you can download the entire API to use offline.

Answer (score 0):

Sun provides downloadable versions of the Java platform documentation.

**[Java SE Downloads](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)**

Scroll down the page and look for the link called Java SE 6 Documentation. It is a series of HTML files covering the entire Java SE JDK. It can be handy to have it stored locally, but because there is no search functionality, its uses are somewhat limited.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly a language you can build docs for Ruby on Rails by doing the following

```
rails sample_project
rake rails:freeze:gems
rake doc:rails
rake rails:unfreeze
```

and then use or take yourself a copy of the doc/api folder

Comment: This is on Linux? In the Terminal or via some program?

Comment: it will work on any platform, where you have a rails install. Each of the commands above are typed on a command line (Terminal) on a line of it's own

Answer (score 0):

You can also [download MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/msdn/Default.aspx) to get documentation for VB.NET, C#, C++ and various Windows & Component APIs

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp has the hyperspec. A complete guide the language and its libraries.

[Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/common-lisp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I actually [mirror a portion of the PHP site](http://php.net/mirroring.php) for myself, just once a week, by RSync (which is quite efficient, only downloading about 1/6th of what a full download would take).

A couple of advantages of a local copy running on my own server is that the shortcuts (for example php.net/array_merge) work, and I've got the full notes as well.

Answer (score 0):

for C#, I just found this offline documentation: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7BBE5EDA-5062-4EBB-83C7-D3C5FF92A373&displaylang=en

beware - large file size.
(still downloading, so hope I'm not misleading anyone here)

Comment: Now sadly we get "404 - File or directory not found."! I think MS are not serious in providing their documentation for C#, always we need to go online for it, which many small developers hate.