# Is the F# language reference documentation available in an offline format (PDF, CHM)?

Tags: f#, documentation, language-specifications

I've found [several](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/post/11179.aspx) [posts](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/post/4325.aspx) on [hubFS](http://cs.hubfs.net/) of people asking if there is, or will be, offline documentation for F#. These posts haven't been answered. So I want to give it a shot and ask the same question here on SO.

---

**Where I've looked for offline documentation so far:**

- The [April 2010 CTP release of Visual F# (version 2.0)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=151924) is available for VS 2008, but it comes without an offline help.
- There's a question on SO about [offline documentation for various programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723017), but F# isn't mentioned there at the time of this writing.
- There is of course Microsoft's [F# language reference documentation (available on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233154.aspx), which could be downloaded for offline browsing using e.g. [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

---

**Question:**

Does anyone know whether any "official" offline documentation is on the way, anytime soon?

(And related to this, even tough it might be hard to answer objectively: Would it be reasonable to expect that F# *won't* undergo ECMA or ISO standardization, ie. there likely won't be a standards document describing the language?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't directly answer the question but the F# language specifications are here:

- F# 3.0 ([PDF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/f-at-microsoft-research/?from=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf), [HTML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/f-at-microsoft-research/?from=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html))
- F# 2.0 ([PDF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/f-at-microsoft-research/?from=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec-2.0-final.pdf), [HTML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/f-at-microsoft-research/?from=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec-2.0-final.html))

These links are taken from the [F# team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fsharpteam/) post ["Updated F# Language Specification for F# 3.0 Now Available"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fsharpteam/updated-f-language-specification-for-f-3-0-now-available).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is now: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharpdocs

I'm hoping this will easily convert to a Dash docset or that there's some local-hosting solution for snappy offline indexing and search.